# CSS not getting applied properly in chrome browser

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have below lines in my JSPX

```
<div class="page_nav">
   <a id="saveButton" class="button"><span>${save}</span></a>           
   <a id="cancelButton" class="button"><span>${cancel}</span></a>
</div>
```

for loading "save" and "cancel" button. When I load the page, the order of the buttons is not ordered, only in chrome. Please refer screen shot for reference

[image: BUTTON NOT DISPLAYED ORDERLY]

Below are the copy-pastes from css

```
a.button {
    background: transparent
        url('../../images/admin/bg_button_span.png') repeat
        scroll top right;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font: normal 1.1em Tahoma, Arial;
    height: 24px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.page_nav {
   float: left;
   margin: 1em 0;
   width: 100%;
   clear: both;
}
```

***This happens only in chrome***

**I use the same div in another page (same classnames too)., it works there perfectly. Not sure what am missing here**

Please help me on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set overflow:hidden for .page_nav:

```
.page_nav {
   float: left;
   display:block;
   margin: 1em 0;
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: @Lowkase Can you please explain what was the problem and how did overflow:hidden property solved it. It would help other readers. Thanks !!

Comment: The OP wasn't clearing the floated children of .page_nav properly.  I simply cleared out the children floats of .page_nav using overflow: hidden.  I prefer to use overflow to clear out my floats, except in certain instances when I have to use a clearfix.  You can read more about clearing floats here: http://www.impressivewebs.com/clearing-floats-why-necessary/